# Getting string from rightside 10 char

Tags: sql, oracle

My table is in oracle toad. teh table contain column name phone number  varchar2 datatype.it contain set of phonenumbers. some numbers are more than 10 char. i want to filter that number from right side 10 char.

```
data's in the table
-------------------
phone number

9948184759
9948220955
994823298612
9948249815
99482599971234
9948277935
9948288258
99483015076789
9948335085
9948337552
9948338134

the above column values are phone numbers.but some numbers are more than 10 char length

that numbers are
----------------
 994823298612
 99482599971234
 99483015076789

 expected output for the above numbers
----------------------------------------
4823298612
2599971234
3015076789

Help me to do this? am new to oracle toad
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by using Substr function for example

```
with T1 as 
( 
  select 99482599971234  n from dual union all
  select 99483015076789 n from dual union all
  select 994823298612 n from dual
) 

select substr(n, Length(n) - 9, 10) nn
  from t1


 Nn 
-------------------
4823298612 
2599971234 
3015076789
```

Comment: my code in aspx.vb select PHONE from  reports.renewal_contact_t where run_date=to_date('" + TextBox1.Text + "','mm/dd/yyyy') and  EXP_DATE =to_date('" + TextBox2.Text + "','mm/dd/yyyy') and  region ='TNP'", cn)

Comment: here itself i want to retrieve phone numbers only 10 digit from right side

Comment: what prevents you from using substr(PHONE, Length(PHONE) - 9, 10) in that query?

Comment: Here is an explanation http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions181.htm#i87066

Comment: - means it takes the char from right its ok. but why u use the number 9 in that function

Comment: @sudha.s, it's because he's counting *backwards* from the end (length) of the string, and `substr`, like most Oracle string functions, start their counting from 1. e.g. if the string is 11 characters long, to get the last 10 characters you'd have to start from the 2nd character, thus 11-9 = 2.

Answer (score 2):

Simpler:

```
select substr(phone_number, -10) from ...
```

Comment: @Jeffery am getting error like not enough arguments for this function

Comment: Works fine for me, tested in Oracle 10g. Show your exact query.

Comment: @jeffery select substr(123456789012 -10) from dual.Running this query in toad for oracle

Comment: (a) `123456789012` is a number, not a string. You said that the column  is a VARCHAR2. (b) you've missed the comma, so you're effectively running `substr(123456789002)` which is obviously wrong.